# Prove that function is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, characteristic-functions, measurable-functions

Prove that the following function is measurable:

$$f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \chi_{[n,n+1]}$$ where $\chi$ is the characteristic function.

I am aware of the definition of a measurable function, however I can't figure out how to prove this one. I would be thankful for some ideas!

Comment: For any $x \in \mathbb R $, if $I_x = (-\infty,x)$ then  $f^{-1}(I_x)$ is an interval.

Comment: Hint: Pointwise limit of measurable functions, is again measurable.